# Need a Firefox 2.0 download link (working)

Tags: firefox, cisco, webex

I am trying to get hold of a Firefox 2.0.x version . I cannot get any working download link . All links are failing. Can anyone help me with a working link?

Why FF2.0?

I am trying to run webex(cisco) which apparently runs only in FF2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. [Mozilla's own ftp](ftp://archive.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/2.0.0.20/)
2. [Filewatcher.com has a tar.gz](ftp://ftp.cesca.es/mirror2/softcatala/softcatala/firefox/2.0.0.11/linux/firefox-2.0.0.11.tar.gz)

I downloaded both but did -not- install them :)
If you need more please leave a comment!

But you are wrong I think. webex works with FF3 and FF4 too.
From the [webex](http://support.webex.com/support/system-requirements.html) website requirements:

```
32-bit Ubuntu 10.x, 32-bit Fedora 12/13,
32-bit Red Hat 5, 32-bit OpenSuSE 11.2/11.3
Firefox 3.x
Mozilla 1.7
JavaScript and cookies enabled
Requires Sun Java 5 or higher
No support for Remote Access
At least 512 MB RAM
```

Comment: thanks. finally got a link. BTW, i am using AT&T webex , which is kind of prehistoric when it comes to Linux support! lol!